# In WPF form My check box in first row of grid get checked after key press in ShowSearchPanelMode , I Don't want to check until i move to grid row?

Tags: c#, wpf

Grid check box get checked when in search Box key is pressed .
Grid should not affect on key press of ShowSearchPanelMode of WPF ! 
XAML Code

```
<dxg:TableView Name="view" ShowTotalSummary="False"  AlternateRowBackground="#FFE5EEF7" AlternationCount="2"
                               ShowSearchPanelMode="Always" 
                               ShowSearchPanelFindButton="True"  
                               SearchPanelFindMode="FindClick" 
                               ShowSearchPanelCloseButton="True" 
                                 ShowGroupPanel="False" AllowColumnMoving="False" 
                               AutoWidth="True" BestFitArea="All"   DetailHeaderContent="True" ShowIndicator="False" 
                               BestFitMode="AllRows" AllowEditing="True"   >
```

c# Code

```
private void dgv_Details_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int RowInd = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Details.GetRowVisibleIndexByHandle(view.FocusedRowData.RowHandle.Value).ToString());
        {
             if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                if (ShowSearchPanelMode.Always.ToString() != "")
                {


                    int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dgv_Details.GetRowVisibleIndexByHandle(view.FocusedRowData.RowHandle.Value).ToString());
                    string itmId = dgv_Details.GetCellValue(RowIndex, "Item Code").ToString();

                    string check_ = "false";


                    itmId = dgv_Details.GetCellValue(RowIndex, "Item Code").ToString();

                    check_ = dgv_Details.GetCellValue(RowIndex, "IsSelect").ToString();
                    if (check_ == "false" || check_ == "False")
                    {
                        check_ = "true";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        check_ = "false";
                    }
                    IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => r["itmId"].ToString() == itmId);
                    rows.ToList().ForEach(r => r.SetField("IsSelect", check_));
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                    dgv_Details.ItemsSource = null;
                    dgv_Details.ItemsSource = dt;
                    dgv_Details.RefreshData();
                }
                dgv_Details.SetFocusedRowCellValue(ShowSearchPanelMode.Default.ToString(), RowInd);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        DXMessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: All your codes are in `KeyDown` event..what else do u expect ?

Comment: when the focus is on the row I want to check/uncheck checkbox with only Enter key press .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't properly understand what you're trying to do  but in your comment you said

> when the focus is on the row I want to check/uncheck checkbox with only Enter key press

The easiest solution i can give you regarding this issue is :

```
private void dgvw_KeyDown()
if (e.Key == Key.Return)
 {
   dgvw.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
   dgvw.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(false);
  }}

 ///Add this if required
 dgvw.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
```

Hope this helps :)